# How to select only selected column of master table and all column of detail table in Linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

```
public partial class Product
{
    public Product()
    {
        this.ProductPrimaryPrices = new HashSet<ProductPrimaryPrice>();
        this.ProductSecondaryPrices = new HashSet<ProductSecondaryPrice>();            
    }

    public int ProductId { get; set; }       
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }        

    public virtual ICollection<ProductPrimaryPrice> ProductPrimaryPrices { get; set; }        
    public virtual ICollection<ProductSecondaryPrice> ProductSecondaryPrices { get; set; }
}
```

From the above code, I want to select only `ProductId`, `Code`, `Name`, and `Description` of `Product` entity and all related properties of `ProductPrimaryPrices` and `ProductSecondaryPrice`, because it is taking to much time to load Image `byte[]` array from the database. I need only the selected columns from `Product` entity and all columns from `ProductPrimaryPrice` and `ProductSecondaryPrices`.

I have already tried with an anonymous type like what follows, but struggling with how to convert the anonymous type back to `Product` again.

```
var tempProduct = (from p in ctx.Products.Include("ProductPrimaryPrices").Include("ProductSecondaryPrices")
                   select new 
                          {
                              ProductId = p.ProductId,                                   
                              Code = p.Code,
                              Name = p.Name,
                              Description = p.Description,                                    
                              ProductPrimaryPrices = p.ProductPrimaryPrices,
                              ProductSecondaryPrices = p.ProductSecondaryPrices                                    
                          }
                  ).ToList();
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: You could select a `new Product { ... }` and set its properties there.  Though honestly I think a cleaner long-term solution would be to move the byte array to another table as a sub-object of `Product` and have that property lazy-load.

Comment: Since you don't have the complete data for a `Product` entity, I don't see how you could ever convert your anonymous type into a `Product`.  Do you intend to use this data (in the anonymous type) to eventually update `Product` entities?  What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks, @David for your comment. I have already tried to select `new Product { ... }` but its give me an exception `The entity or complex type 'Product' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query`. And also moving byte array to another table is really good idea

Comment: @STLDeveloper For converting anonymous type to a `Product` I have created separate method in which I am creating instance of `Product` class using reflection and assigning each property value to `Product` instance

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got an answer after some brain storming

Now, I am able to convert anonymous type to `Product` type by using reflection. I have implemented one method which converts anonymous type to 'Product' type and then one by one I am looping anonymous type and convert it into `Product` type by calling a newly implemented method.

Following is an implementation

```
public List<Product> GetProduct()
{
    List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
    using (var ctx = new PosEntities())
    {
        var tempProducts = 
            (from p in ctx.Products.Include("ProductPrimaryPrices").Include("ProductSecondaryPrices").Include("ProductsModifiers")
            where (p.MenuGroupId == menuGroupId && p.Active) && (p.ProductPrimaryPrices.Any(x => x.OutletId == outletId && x.Active))
            select new 
            {
                ProductId = p.ProductId,
                Code = p.Code,
                Name = p.Name,
                Description = p.Description,                
                ProductPrimaryPrices = p.ProductPrimaryPrices,
                ProductSecondaryPrices = p.ProductSecondaryPrices,
                ProductsModifiers = p.ProductsModifiers
            }).ToList();                    

        foreach (object anonymous in tempProducts)
        {
            Product product = (Product)Utility.ToType<Product>(anonymous, new Product());
            products.Add(product);
        }
        return products;
    }
}
```

Following is method which converts anonymous type to `Product` type

```
public static class Utility
    {
        public static object ToType<T>(this object obj, T type)
        {
            //create instance of T type object:            
            object tmp = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(type.ToString()));

            //loop through the properties of the object you want to covert:          
            foreach (PropertyInfo pi in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                try
                {
                    //get the value of property and try to assign it to the property of T type object:
                    tmp.GetType().GetProperty(pi.Name).SetValue(tmp, pi.GetValue(obj, null), null);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // Logging.Log.Error(ex);
                }
            }
            //return the T type object:         
            return tmp;
        }       
    }
```

Comment: Did you consider using David's suggestion of changing your `new {...}` selector into `new Product {...}`? Seems simpler than writing your own version of AutoMapper. Less error-prone, too, since a property rename on `Product` won't break the mapping.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior I have already tried that but its throws me an error with "The entity or complex type 'Product' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query"